# No puedo acomodar el menú principal con los componentes de las rutas en mi layout principal con Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-router

tengo una menú de tipo barra lateral en el cual se expande y se contrae cada vez que se le da click en un boton hamburguesa, resulta que en el layout principal tengo este componente con un `<outlet-router>` para imprimir en las rutas cada ruta del menú a un lado de la barra lateral. Ahora lo que pasa es que la interfaz de las rutas quedan detrás de la barra lateral y me gustaria que estuvieran a un lado de está barra y según se habrá o se cierre la barra lateral pues que el contenido de las rutas también se expandan y se extiendan.

Así es como se ve, no se puede ver el contenido de la ruta que estoy en ese momento que es dashboard:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando contraigo la barra lateral, el contenido de la ruta en la que estoy aparece estando dentras de la barra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria que el contenido de las rutas aparecieran al lado de la barra lateral y que este contenido se expanda y se extienda según se abra o se cierre la barra.

Este es el código que tengo en el layout principal donde renderizo la barra y los componentes de las rutas:

```
<div>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
</div>
<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Pensé que encerrando con los div podría conseguir este efecto pero no :/. Quiero aclarar que no tengo nada en los estilos de este componente principal
**Agradecería mucho si alguien supiera hacer este efecto compañeros**

Este es el el html del componente de la barra lateral por si lo necesitan ver compañeros:

```
<header>
    <div id="sidemenu" class="menu-collapsed" [class.menu-expanded]="activeMenu">
      <!-- HEADER -->
        <div class="header">
          <div class="title"><span>Administrador</span></div>
          <!--Boton hamburguesa:-->
          <div class="menu-btn" (click)="toggleActiveMenu()">
              <!--Estos 3 divs me ayudaran a crear el icono de la hamburguesa:-->
              <div class="btn-hamburguer"></div>
              <div class="btn-hamburguer"></div>
              <div class="btn-hamburguer"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- PROFILE -->
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="photo"><img src="../../../assets/images/perfil mym.jpg"></div>
            <div class="name"><span>Javier Mejía</span></div>
        </div>
        <!-- ITEMS MENU -->
        <div class="menu-items">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-text" routerLink="home">
                  <div class="icon"><img src="../../../assets//images/home-icon.png"></div>
                  <div class="title"><a>Home</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-text" routerLink="empleados">
                  <div class="icon"><img src="../../../assets//images/employee-icon.png"></div>
                  <div class="title"><a>Empleados</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-text" routerLink="dashboard">
                  <div class="icon"><img src="../../../assets//images/dashboard-icon.png"></div>
                  <div class="title"><a>Dashboard</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**EDICIÓN:**
Para dar mas información este es el css del componente de la barra lateral, lo trabaje con scss:

```
#sidemenu{
  background-color: var(--sidebar-primary-color);
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#sidemenu a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* HEADER */
#sidemenu .header{
  box-sizing: border-box;//Para que no se hagan espacios adicionales
  border-bottom: solid 1px var(--sidebar-secundary-color);
}
#sidemenu .header .title{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#sidemenu .header .title, .menu-btn{
  vertical-align: middle;//Verticalizamos la posicion de las capaz para el boton hamburguesa
}
#sidemenu .header .menu-btn{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  width: var(--sidebarmenu-width-collapsed);//la variable es igual a 50px
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sidemenu .header .menu-btn:hover{
  background-color: var(--sidebar-secundary-color);
}
#sidemenu .header .menu-btn .btn-hamburguer{
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

/* Profile */
#sidemenu .profile{
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 1px var(--sidebar-secundary-color);
  padding: 10px;
  .photo{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    img{
      width: 45%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  }
  .name{
    font-size: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
#sidemenu .menu-items{
  overflow: hidden;
  .item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    .item-text{
      margin: 0px 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      display: flex;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--sidebar-secundary-color);
      overflow: hidden;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      a{
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 17px;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 11px;
      }
      .icon img{
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        margin-top: 9px;
        margin-left: 17px;
      }
    }
    .item-text:hover{
      background-color: var(--sidebar-secundary-color);
    }
  }

}


//Ahora trabajamos en la clase menu-collapsed:
.menu-collapsed{
  width: 50px;
  .header .title{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .profile .photo{
    width: 100%;
    img{
      width: 60%;
      height: auto;
    }
  }
  .profile .name{
    display: none;
  }
  .menu-items .item{
    width: 100%;
  }

  //Cuando le menu sidebar este expandido:
  &.menu-expanded{
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5); //Para saber que el menu sidebar esta expandido
    .header .title{
      width: calc(100% - 50px);
      margin-right: -5px;
      padding: 20px;

      span{
        width: calc( 300px - 50px - 5px);//La medida para el span es le ancho del sidebar- los 50px de los iconos de cada menu - 5px
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
    .profile .photo{

      img{
        height: 127px;
      }
    }
    .profile .name{
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: A pesar de que el contenedor de la barra lateral no tiene ningún estilo, puedo apreciar que dentro del componente existen clases que definen como se posiciona tu menú como por ejemplo 'menu-collapsed', Creo que nos faltaría ver los estilos para tener mas información, sin embargo quiero pensar que el posicionamiento es "fixed", por eso el contenido de las vistas se queda atrás, como idea rápida, podrías agregarle un margen o padding izquierdo al contenedor del router-outlet del ancho de tu barra lateral cuando esta oculto y aumentarlo cuando la barra se muestra.

Comment: Eres un genio Carlos, te diste cuenta que la posición de la barra es fixed, voy a editar el post para agregar el css que tiene el componente de la barra lateral, para proporcionarte mayor información. A parte de eso poniendo atención a tu ultima sugerencia, tendría que mandar la acción del click al presionar el botón hamburguesa con un @output hacia el componente layout principal y allí dependiendo de esa acción si es true o false hacer eso que dices de colocar un margin izquierdo al contenedor del router que cambie según se expanda o no la barra lateral, cierto?

Comment: @Hugo Una vez recibes el booleano no tienes más que añadir un `ngClass` con la clase bindeada a tu booleano, angular se encargará de aplicarla cuando el boolean sea true y quitarla cuando no: `[ngClass]="{'moreWidth': thisBooleanIsTrue}"`. Puedes añadir cuantas clases quieras dentro de los corchetes, es muy práctico para casos como este.

Comment: @Benito-B Gracias, antes de hacer cualquier cosa, probé quitando la posición de fixed al sidebar menú y le añadí un display block, con eso el contenido de las rutas ya no aparecen detrás del sidebar sino que al lado y además se expande y se contrae cuando el sidebar se cierra y abre. Era lo que quería, gracias de nuevo :D